# Integrate Sencha Touch with .Net

Tags: .net, sencha-touch

I want to learn Sencha Touch and looking for some example/Tutorials/Books etc which show some Sencha Touch/.Net integration. It some one can show me how to populate DropDown/List etc using MVC .Net that would be great.